# jquery import not working on IE, Firefox, Safari

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, firefox, import

I have succeeded importing same header and footer on all my pages, I always uses Chrome then when I tried to open the site im working at on IE and Firefox they do not display my header and footer.

What am I missing?

Firefox showed this message
[click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0gix.jpg)

While IE showed none.

Here is my code for importing

```
<link rel="import" id="allheader" href="header.html">

<script>

            var getImport  = document.querySelector('#allheader');
            var getContent = getImport.import.querySelector('#header');
            document.body.appendChild(document.importNode(getContent, true));
        </script>
```

What do i need to do? thank you

Comment: Could you find me some docs on the .import function you're using above?

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda hi, i edited my post, Is that what you need?

Comment: Not exactly, I'm wondering if there is documentation online for the `import` function used in `getImport.import.querySelector('#header');`

Comment: oh i see.. 

[http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML imports are NOT currently supported in browsers other then Chrome and Opera. Checkout [this link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports) for the full browser support list. [Firefox will not ship with imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports), and they don't plan to any time soon.

I suggest you use a polyfill, like Google's [webcomponents.js](http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/). Checkout the page on [HTML Imports](http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/html-imports/).